# Is there a way to save the changes mage to local storage in ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, local-storage

I have been trying to implement a cart function to my e-commerce . In this cart function when ever I add an item, if its already present in the cart we must increase the quantity. Everything works fine but whenever I refresh the browser or add a new item the values get reverted. How can I fix this.

My frontend is ember.js v3.4.4 and Backend Ruby on Rails v7.0.2.3

The addon I'm using for localstorage is ember-localstorage-addon

Below I have attached a snippet how I add elements to the cart

```js
// app/service/shopping-cart.js

addItem(itemId){
    const itemArray = this.itemsIds.content;
    const index = itemArray.findIndex(object => object.id === itemId.id);
    const itemElement = itemArray[index];
    console.log(itemElement);
    if(itemElement){

        console.log(itemId);
        const quantityOfAddedElement = parseInt(itemId.quantity) + parseInt(itemElement.quantity);
        console.log(quantityOfAddedElement);
        const totalPrice = parseInt(itemId.price) + parseInt(itemElement.price);
        itemElement.quantity = quantityOfAddedElement;
        itemElement.price = totalPrice;
        console.log(quantityOfAddedElement);
    }
    else{
        this.get('itemsIds').addObject((itemId));
    }
}
```

```js
// app/controller/product.js
actions:{
    addToItem(model){
        const id = model.id;
        const title = model.title;
        const quantity = this.quantity;
        const images = model.images;
        const price = quantity * model.price;
        const dbQuantity = model.quantity;

        this.shoppingCart.addItem({
            id,
            title, 
            price,
            quantity,
            images,
        });
    },
 }
```

Comment: Hello!!


can you clarify what the issue is?

localStorage is all string-based data, so... as long as you can serialize to / from that, you can do anything ✨

Answer (score 1):

You can read from and write to local storage in Ember.js using plain JavaScript:

```js
// reading shopping cart items from local storage
const shoppingCartItems = JSON.parse(
  window.localStorage.getItem('shoppingCartItems')
);

// writing shopping cart items to local storage
shoppingCartItems.push('myItemId');
window.localStorage.setItem(
  'shoppingCartItems',
  JSON.stringify(shoppingCartItems)
);
```

Additionally you should listen for local storage events caused by changing local storage in another browser tab and update your local state accordingly.

To ease all this, I have written the [ember-local-storage-decorator](https://github.com/jelhan/ember-local-storage-decorator). It provides a `@localStorage` decorator. A class property decorated with it will reflect the local storage value. It is integrated with autotracking.